# Cannot dismiss modally presented AVPlayerViewController while hotspot is active

Tags: fullscreen, statusbar, navigationbar, avplayerviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

My app presents an `AVPlayerViewController` full screen, using `modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen`. Normally, everything works fine, and the `AVPlayerViewController` can be dismissed by the `Done` (here: `Fertig`) button in the top status bar of the `AVPlayerViewController`:

[image]

However, when I have an active hotspot connection, the hotspot status bar hides the top status bar of the `AVPlayerViewController` including the `Done` button, and the `AVPlayerViewController` can no longer be dismissed while the hotspot is active:

[image]

How do I have to configure the `AVPlayerViewController` correctly?

Comment: @Yuchen Zhong You are right. I simply did not realize that the bottom bar had changed. Too stupid. If you like, make your comment to an answer so that I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom bar has an exit full-screen mode button at the lower right corner.

[image]

So the user can simply use that to exit the full-screen mode when the hotspot is active.